# Apply Conditional Formatting to Entire Row Specific Only to That Row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create Conditional Formatting that has multiple different rules based off different values, that will only apply to the row that the value matches in. Here is the code I have so far for some context.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);

// Create a cell
row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Lot Type");
row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Lot Size");
row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Square Footage");
row1.createCell(3).setCellValue("Heating/Cooling");
row1.createCell(4).setCellValue("Extras");

XSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
row2.createCell(0).setCellValue("Residential");
row2.createCell(1).setCellValue("8000");
row2.createCell(2).setCellValue("1200");
row2.createCell(3).setCellValue("Yes");
row2.createCell(4).setCellValue("None");

XSSFRow row3 = sheet.createRow(1);
row3.createCell(0).setCellValue("Industrial");
row3.createCell(1).setCellValue("12000");
row3.createCell(2).setCellValue("8000");
row3.createCell(3).setCellValue("");
row3.createCell(4).setCellValue("");

// Set conditional rules
SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("$A2 = " + "\"" + "Residential" + "\"");
PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C2"), CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E2")};

ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions,cfRules);

// Write the output to a file
return wb;
```

So this works, but only if Row 2 A column has the value "Residential" entered. What I want to happen, is "Lot Type" will have a drop down list with different options ('Residential', 'Industrial', 'Agriculture', etc) and each "Lot Type" would have different "required" fields, and I don't know what the user will select per row for each row.

The possible options, both in terms of rows and possible drop downs choices, is large. At the moment, 10000 rows are generated each with 40+ drop down options. That isn't specifically necessary information, but what it does mean is that simply looping through i < 10000 and just incrementing the row index; "A#", "C#", etc, and then with each index looping through all my drop down option rules, is not a viable solution.

If that is the only option, so be it, but I was hoping there was a way I could do something with Excel equations or conditional formatting where I can connect the different "Lot Types" to their required columns, with the numbered index of the row dynamically used within the equation itself. Which means I would be able to just set the conditional formatting once on the possible rows, and not have to run through some massive double loop.

Something like the following, which I have tried and it did not work:

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("$A$ = " + "\"" + "Residential" + "\"");
PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C$"), CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E$")};
```

How I would envision this to work in words would be that what ever row index has the value "Residential" inputted into the A cell, it would cause that respective row's, and only that row's, C and E cells to be highlighted

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is not really good at pointing the user to the required cells to fill in. As long as always the same columns needs to be filled, either data validation or conditional formatting offer themselves. But if the mandatory columns are conditional by them self, then this leads very fast to thousands of different data validation or conditional formatting rules. And this is not practicable as you mentioned already.

But the question you asked was about a conditional formula rule which gets adjusted to different rows automatically. And this is possible.

Conditional formula rules, as well as default formulas, respect the `$` mark in cell references to differentiate between fixed and variable cell references. So if a formula rule `=($A2="Residential")` gets applied to the range `A2:E1000`, then the row reference to row 2 gets adjusted in other rows because it is variable and not fixed by `$`. So it checks `=($A2="Residential")` in row 2, `=($A3="Residential")` in row 3, `=($A4="Residential")` in row 4 and so on.

But of course the conditional formatting gets applied to all the columns in the given range `A2:E1000`. So if the rule matches in a row, all columns `A:E` get formatted. And this is the problem. If only the required columns shall be highlighted, then there would must be multiple different cell ranges where the conditional formatting gets applied. And this leads to your mentioned thousands of possibilities in your case.

One solution, I can think of, would be having different formula rules per identifier (Lot Type in your case) which may have different rules for required columns per identifier. And as long one of those rules is violated, then the whole row gets highlighted. This would be solvable having as much conditional formatting rules as different identifiers are, all applied to the whole data range.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormattingRulesAndRanges {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
   new Object[] {"Lot Type", "Lot Size", "Square Footage", "Heating/Cooling", "Extras"},
   new Object[] {"Residential", 8000, 1200, "Yes", "None"},
   new Object[] {"Industrial", 12000, 8000, "", ""},
   new Object[] {"Agriculture", 4000, 900, "No", "Much"},
   new Object[] {"Industrial", 10000, "", "Yes", ""},
   new Object[] {"Residential", 8500, 1000, "", "None"},
   new Object[] {"Agriculture", 9000, "", "", ""}
  };
  int dataRowCount = data.length;
  int columnCount = data[0].length;
  
  String[] identifiers = new String[] {"Residential", "Industrial", "Agriculture"};
  String[] requiredColumnsRules = new String[] {"OR($C2=\"\",$D2=\"\",$E2=\"\")", "OR($C2=\"\",$D2=\"\")", "$C2=\"\""};
  int identifiersCount = identifiers.length;
 
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath ="./ConditionalFormattingRulesAndRanges.xlsx";
  int lastRow = workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastRowIndex();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  
  int r = 0;
  for (Object[] rowData : data) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   int c = 0;
   for (Object cellValue : rowData) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (cellValue instanceof Number) {
     cell.setCellValue(((Number)cellValue).doubleValue());   
    } else {
     cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(cellValue));
    }
    c++;
   }
   r++;   
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);   
  }
  sheet.createFreezePane(1,1,1,1);

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(identifiers) ;
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, lastRow, 0, 0);
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.createPromptBox("Hint", "If the line is highlighted in yellow, mandatory fields are not filled out.");
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);


  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[identifiersCount];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < identifiersCount; i++) {
   String identifier = identifiers[i];
   String requiredColumnsRule = requiredColumnsRules[i];
      
   String formulaRule = "AND($A2 = " + "\"" + identifier + "\"," + requiredColumnsRule + ")"; // rule will be applied from row 2 on; Row reference is not fixed, so it will be adjusted
  
   ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(formulaRule);
   PatternFormatting patternFmt = rule.createPatternFormatting();
   patternFmt.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
  
   cfRules[i] = rule;
  }
  
  CellRangeAddress[] dataRange = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A2:E" + lastRow)}; // rules applied to the whole possible data range  
  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(dataRange, cfRules);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Another solution would be having one conditional formatting rule per mandatory column. That rule would must define per formula for which identifiers this column is a mandatory column. This needs one complete conditional formatting for each mandatory column.

Complete example for this:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormattingRulesAndRanges2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
   new Object[] {"Lot Type", "Lot Size", "Square Footage", "Heating/Cooling", "Extras"},
   new Object[] {"Residential", 8000, 1200, "Yes", "None"},
   new Object[] {"Industrial", 12000, 8000, "", ""},
   new Object[] {"Agriculture", 4000, 900, "No", "Much"},
   new Object[] {"Industrial", 10000, "", "Yes", ""},
   new Object[] {"Residential", 8500, 1000, "", "None"},
   new Object[] {"Agriculture", 9000, "", "", ""}
  };
  int dataRowCount = data.length;
  int columnCount = data[0].length;
  
  String[] identifiers = new String[] {"Residential", "Industrial", "Agriculture"};
  String[] rules = new String[] { // rule will be applied from row 2 on; Row reference is not fixed, so it will be adjusted
   "AND($C2=\"\",OR($A2=\"Residential\",$A2=\"Industrial\",$A2=\"Agriculture\"))", // column C needs to be filled for all identifiers
   "AND($D2=\"\",OR($A2=\"Residential\",$A2=\"Industrial\"))", // column D needs to be filled for Residential and Industrial only 
   "AND($E2=\"\",OR($A2=\"Residential\"))" // column E needs to be filled for Residential only   
  };
  int rulesCount = rules.length; 
  
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath ="./ConditionalFormattingRulesAndRanges.xlsx";
  int lastRow = workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastRowIndex();
  
  CellRangeAddress[][] rulesAppliedTo = new CellRangeAddress[][] {
   new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C2:C" + lastRow)},   
   new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("D2:D" + lastRow)},   
   new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E2:E" + lastRow)}
  };
 
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  
  int r = 0;
  for (Object[] rowData : data) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   int c = 0;
   for (Object cellValue : rowData) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (cellValue instanceof Number) {
     cell.setCellValue(((Number)cellValue).doubleValue());   
    } else {
     cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(cellValue));
    }
    c++;
   }
   r++;   
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);   
  }
  sheet.createFreezePane(1,1,1,1);

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(identifiers) ;
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, lastRow, 0, 0);
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.createPromptBox("Hint", "If a cell is highlighted in yellow, then this is a mandatory.");
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  for (int i = 0; i < rulesCount; i++) {
   String formulaRule = rules[i];
  
   ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(formulaRule);
   PatternFormatting patternFmt = rule.createPatternFormatting();
   patternFmt.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
  
   ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};   
   CellRangeAddress[] appliedTo = rulesAppliedTo[i]; 
   sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(appliedTo, cfRules);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```